# SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill

Tags: networking, wireless, airplane-mode

I'm trying to get Ubuntu to enable Wifi automatically on boot
currently I get "Airplane mode" on boot and I have to manually turn on the Wireless adapter

I've created /etc/rc.local (which doesn't exist in Ubuntu 17.10)

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
sudo reboot
```

and add this commands

```
sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

wlo1 is my wireless adapter connection name

When I turn off my wireless connection I automatically get the Airplane mode (which has a dedicated shortcut in my keyboard FN+F12 that doesn't work) and when I run the the command `sudo ifconfig wlo1 up` I get this error message `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill`

There is no option to enable/disable the the Airplane switch via a HW setting in my BIOS as suggested [Here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-wireless-networking-41/siocsifflags-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill-4175602737/)

Is there a way to automatically turn on my wireless network upon boot ?